# Handle data between two completely separate React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rebuilding and replacing parts of an older e-commerce systems product page with parts written in React.
Instead of rewriting the whole thing I'm doing it component by component and later on in the project I'm going to connect it in a more conventional way.
But for now it's just part by part.

I'm currently trying to figure out how to handle data between two components, a ProductList and a Cart. The two components live in entire different places on the product page.
If I'm pressing Add to cart in the ProductList I want the Cart to be able to react to that event, as well as pressing Empty cart in the Cart to trigger a change in the ProductList.

The components won't be siblings.

Basic structure of the app:

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- Lots of other stuff, PHP etc... -->
        <div id="list"></div>
        <!-- Lots of other stuff, PHP etc... -->
    </div>
    <!-- Lots of other stuff, PHP etc... -->
    <div id="cart"></div>
    <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript components:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import List from "./components/List";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";

ReactDOM.render(
<List />,
document.getElementById('list')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Cart />,
    document.getElementById('cart')
);
```

Since neither are a child to a common ancestor, how would I go about handling component communication in a good way?

Comment: A common technique for when two sibling components need to interact is to [lift the state up to the first common ancestor](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). You could e.g. create an `App` component that keeps both your cart and product list, and renders `Cart` and `List` and passes the data down as props.

Comment: @Tholle Yes, that would be the way to go. But I'm sorry I forgot to specify that the components won't be siblings at all unfortunately. I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: Alright. If you can't lift the state up, it's probably a good idea to introduce a state management libray, like [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) or [Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Redux library, https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react
it could have a reducer for the cart store,
And List and Cart component should e wrapped with container components that would be connected with cart store.

Also, you could use context API that was added in react 16.3 version
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-react-16-3-context-api-basics-53382372dc35

I would say solution with redux is more preferable for this issue.